# How to change value from first line in one newly added column

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file named file1.txt where below data is there

```
APPLICATION ODATE       IF_EXECUTING  APPLICATION_STATUS
Job1        20200731    Post          NOTOK
Job2        20200731    Post          NOTOK
Job3        20200731    Post          NOTOK
JOb3        20200731    Post          NOTOK
```

Adding one new column using below command.

```
awk -v column=4 -v value="four" 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t\t\t";}{for ( i = NF + 1; i > column; i-- ) {$i = $(i-1);}$i = value;print $0;}' file1.txt
```

Output:

```
APPLICATION ODATE       IF_EXECUTING  APPLICATION_STATUS                      four
Job1        20200731    Post          NOTOK                   four
JOb2        20200731    Post          NOTOK                   four
Job3        20200731    Post          NOTOK                   four
JOb4        20200731    Post          NOTOK                   four
```

Here adding three "\t" character. First line "four" should be spaced with APPLICATION_STATUS with just one \t and first line "four" should be replaced with "CYCLE_NUMER"

Desired output:

```
APPLICATION ODATE       IF_EXECUTING  APPLICATION_STATUS    CYCLE_NUMBER
Job1        20200731    Post          NOTOK                 four
JOb2        20200731    Post          NOTOK                 four
Job3        20200731    Post          NOTOK                 four
JOb4        20200731    Post          NOTOK                 four
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v val="four" -v header="CYCLE_NUMBER" '
FNR==1{
  print $0,header
  next
}
{
  print $0,val
}
'  Input_file | column -t
```

OR as per @Cyrus sir's comment in case you want to do within `awk` itself then try following.

```
awk -v val="\t\t\tfour" -v header="\tCYCLE_NUMBER" '
FNR==1{
  print $0,header
  next
}
{
  print $0,val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code. 2nd solution is also more alike 1st solution only thing 2nd one doesn't have `column` command in it and TAB printing is getting handled within `awk` variables itself.

```
awk -v val="four" -v header="CYCLE_NUMBER" '   ##Starting awk program from here with val value of four and header value of CYCLE_NUMBER here.
FNR==1{                           ##Checking condition if FNR==1 then do following.
  print $0,header                 ##Printing current line and header value here.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0,val                    ##Printing current line with val here.
}
'  Input_file | column -t         ##Mentioning Input_file name here and sending output of awk command to column command to get it in good manner.
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `-v val="\t\t\tfour" -v header="\tCYCLE_NUMBER"` and remove `| column -t`.

Comment: `print $0, (NR>1 ? val : header)`

Comment: When I am using 

awk -v val="\t\t\tfour" -v header="\tCYCLE_NUMBER" 'FNR==1{print $0,header}{print $0, (NR>1 ? val : header)}'  file1.txt

It is adding extra line of header like below


APPLICATION ODATE       IF_EXECUTING  APPLICATION_STATUS    CYCLE_NUMBER
APPLICATION ODATE       IF_EXECUTING  APPLICATION_STATUS    CYCLE_NUMBER

Comment: @SourinBiswas, both solutions worked fine for me but you could try my 1st solution once with `column` command and let me know if that helped you?

Comment: @SourinBiswas you removed the `next` statement from the posted script. Don't re-type answers you get here, copy/paste them.

Comment: @SourinBiswas, could you please do let me know if these solutions worked for you?